# View processes not stopped when streaming with python flask

Tags: python, flask

I use a simple Flask application with gunicorn's gevent worker to serve server-sent events.

To stream the content, i use:

```
response = Response(eventstream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

which streams events from redis:

```
def eventstream():
    for message in pubsub.listen():
        # ...
        yield str(event)
```

deployed with:

```
gunicorn -k gevent -b 127.0.0.1:50008 flaskapplication
```

But after its used for a while, i have 50 redis connections open, even when no one is connected to the server-sent events stream anymore.

It seems, like the view does not terminate, because gunicorn is non-blocking and pubsub.listen() is blocking.

How can i fix this? Should i limit the number of processes gunicorn may spawn, or should flask kill the view after some timeout? If possible, it should stop the view/redis connections on inactivity, without disconnecting users, who are still connected to the SSE stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `Timeout` object from natdempk's solution, the most elegant solution is to send a heartbeat, to detect dead connections:

```
while True:
    pubsub = redis.pubsub()
    try:
        with Timeout(30) as timeout:
            for message in pubsub.listen():
                # ...
                yield str(event)
                timeout.cancel()
                timeout.start()
    except Timeout, t:
        if t is not timeout:
            raise
        else:
            yield ":\n\n"  # heartbeat
```

Note that you need to call `redis.pubsub()` again, because the redis connection is lost after the exception and you will get an error `NoneType object has no attribute readline`.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `gunicorn` with `-t <seconds>` to specify a timeout for your workers which will kill them if they are silent for a number of seconds, usually 30 is typical. I think this should work for your issue, but not completely sure.

From what I've seen, it seems like you could also rewrite your worker to use `Timeout` from `gevent`.

This might look something like the following:

```
from gevent import Timeout

def eventstream():
    pubsub = redis.pubsub()
    try:
        with Timeout(30) as timeout:
            pubsub.subscribe(channel)
            for message in pubsub.listen():
                # ...
                yield str(event)
    except Timeout, t:
        if t is not timeout:
            raise
        else:
            pubsub.unsubscribe(channel)
```

[This example](https://gist.github.com/NorthIsUp/1672183) was helpful for getting a hang of how this should work.

Comment: Thank you, this is already very helpful. But the answer i am looking for is some way to detect disconnects. For example gunicorn could raise an exception on disconnect or something like this.